# Finding a constant $ z $ such that $ P(Z \leq z) = 0.95 $ when $ Z \sim \text{N}(0,1) $.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

This is for a homework assignment on normal distributions.

Question:

a) Find a constant $z$ such that $P(Z \leq z) = 0.95$

b) Find a constant $z$ such that $P(Z \geq z) = 0.95$

I'm having trouble understanding what a question wants in regards to normal distributions. I get that it wants me to find a constant $z$, but I don't know what that constant means or is.

For part a, from my notes, it states that $P(X \leq x_p) = p$ refers to the percentile. And since p = 0.95, it's asking me to find what the probability is below the 95th percentile? At the same time, my notes state this formula (with no explanation..) that $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$, where $z$ is a $z-score$. But what is this and what does it have to even do with these problems?

I apologize if this question makes it seem like I'm trying to have someone do my homework, but I'm honestly confused about this entire section. I'd appreciate any help or even any links that could explain normal distributions in more understandable terms.

Comment: Have you guys talked about probability density function?

Comment: He gave us a formula which he stated as a probability density function in a previous section, however I have no idea what it actually means :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Z\le z)=\int_{-\infty}^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dz=0.95$

Or if probability density function has not been covered, just consider the picture of a normal distribution. We know that $Pr(Z\le z)=0.5$ when $z=0$ since $0$ is in the middle. Now, move $z$ to the right, the probability will become larger. When should we stop?

Comment: This makes a little bit more sense actually. Is z allowed to be larger then 1 though? I'm ending up with z = 1.64

Comment: If you are referring to the little $z$, then it's possible that $z>1$. In fact, $z$ could range from$-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

> At the same time, my notes state this formula (with no explanation..)
>   that $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$, where $z$ is a $z-score$. But what
>   is this and what does it have to even do with these problems?

Suppose you have a random variable X, which is $ \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2 )$ distributed-with $\mu\neq 0$ and/or $\sigma^2\neq 1$. Now you want to calculate $P(X \leq x)$ and you have only a table of a standard normal distribution. Thus the table contains only values of a $\mathcal N(0,1 )$ distributed variable. The following equation shows a useful relation:

$P(X\leq x)=P(Z\leq z)=\Phi \left( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)$

$\Phi \left( z\right)$ is the function of the standard normal distribution.

$Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

Example:

Your variable X is $ \mathcal N(4, 9)$ distributed. And you want to calculate the probability, that X is smaller than 5. The equation becomes

$P(X\leq 5)=P(Z\leq \frac 13)=\Phi \left( \frac{5 - 4}{3 }\right)=\Phi (\frac 13)$

If you look at [this table](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf) you will see, that $P(X\leq 5)\approx \Phi (0.33)=0.6230$

Comment: Thanks, I see why I would need this now :)

Answer (score 2):

(a) If you are using at a normal table, first determine whether it 
gives areas $P(Z \le z)$ [or $P(0 < Z \le z)].$ In the first
instance look in the *body* of the table to find the closest
probability to .9500; in this case, probably a tie between .9496 and .0505. Then find the corresponding value of $z$ by looking at the
*margins*; in this case, 1.64 or 1.65, so split the difference
and say $z = 1.645.$ [In the second case, you'll look for the
closest probability to .4500, eventually obtaining the same result.]

(b) By symmetry, it is $z = -1.645.$

If you are using statistical software, then you can get these using the
'inverse CDF' or 'quantile' function. You will get more places of accuracy than from normal tables. In R, it is:

```
 qnorm(.95)    # (a)
 ## 1.644854
 qnorm(.05)    # (b) Same as P(Z <= z) = .05
 ## -1.644854
```

In Minitab:

```
 MTB > invcdf .95;
 SUBC> norm.

 Inverse Cumulative Distribution Function 
 Normal with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1

 P( X <= x )        x
        0.95  1.64485
```

Almost all statistical software packages have something like this,
but each has its own syntax for input and formatting for output.

*Addendum:* I just noticed the nice example from @calculus. In software, you
can sometimes work such problems without 'standardizing'; that is, without subtracting the mean and dividing the difference by the SD. The answer is a little different because software doesn't need to round to two places before table look-up. (Not that the
small difference matters for most practical purposes.)

```
 pnorm(5, 4, sqrt(9))
 ## 0.6305587
```

Comment: We are starting to use R so this is very helpful. As a side note, am I understanding standard deviation wrong? I was told that for a graph of a normal distribution, the center is at 0 and the area to the right is the standard deviation (at 1). So how could I get a value 1.64? The way he talked about it, was that z would be a point along the x of the graph..

Comment: Certainly, z is on the axis. For standard normal the center is at 0, half of the area under the curve on either side. For the standard normal the SD is 1. The area between $\pm 1$ is about 0.68. The area between 0 and 1 is about .34. The area below -1 about 0.16. Try to draw sketches. Can you figure out why, in R, the statement 'pnorm(1)' returns 0.8413447?